# Fatal error idk where?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int new[5] = {66,75,2,43,99} ;
    cout << new[3] << endl ;
}
```

I have an error here and I don't know why.  I wish someone can tell the error and how to fix it?

I tried changing `#include <iostream>` with something else still getting Fatal error?

```
iostream : No such file or directory
 #include < iostream >
                      ^
compilation terminated.
Fatal error: $this->db->where()->join()->num_rows
```

Comment: `new` is a [reserved keyword](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword). You can't use it as an identifier for your variable.

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: iam using https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c_compiler#

Comment: There are many different ways to get fatal errors. The error with Do not assume that because you fixed one error that there isn't another. `#include < iostream >` is different from the error you get with `#include <iostream>`. I happen to know that online gdb will give different error messages for different errors, so I strongly recommend that you do different things  in response to different errors.

Comment: i have changed new with Mostafa its #include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
    int Mostafa[5] = {66,75,2,43,99} ;
    cout << Mostafa[3] << endl ;
}

Comment: fatal error:  iostream: No such file or directory
compilation terminated. this is the error i get from the online compiler

Comment: the error was from the compiler : onlinegdb.com/online_c_compiler# i am using https://www.codechef.com/ide and used it for the same code it worked thnx for help

Comment: Did you change the language from `C` to `C++` on that online compiler? (drop-down list on top-right) They are not the same language...

Comment: You may want to remove the `c++builder` tag since you are not using the C++ builder compiler.

Comment: The code you put in the comments works fine for me: https://ideone.com/dsgRDy

Answer (score 0):

2 errors:
1. New is a keyword,cant be used.
2. the main function must return a value.

http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/107063/

Comment: 1. requires a slight rewording: "`new` is a keyword and can't be reassigned." 2. is incorrect. If nothing is returned from `main`, code to `return 0` is generated by default.